# Files.list returns null for android data/data device is rooted

Tags: android, root, android-file

I'm trying to generate a list of all the files in a particular directory in `/data/data/` e.g. `/data/data/com.package.ect` so that I can zip them. My device is rooted and I've granted Super User to my app. When pass the path to the directory it gets past the if statement, so it recognises that what I'm trying to access is a directory, yet File.list() returns null. I'm assuming I'm still lacking some sort of permission.

```
/**
     * Traverse a directory and get all files,
     * and add the file into fileList
     * @param node file or directory
     */
    public void generateFileList(File node) {

        //add file only
        if (node.isFile()) {
            fileList.add(generateZipEntry(node.getAbsoluteFile().toString()));
        }

        if (node.isDirectory()) {
            String[] subNote = node.list();
            for (String filename : subNote) {
                generateFileList(new File(node, filename));
            }
        }
    }
```

*EDIT: As requested where generateFileList is called

```
public void zipDirectory(String outputPath){

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        try{
            checkStorageDirExists(SDCARD, STORAGE_LOCATION);
            generateFileList(new File(path));
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(SDCARD + STORAGE_LOCATION + outputPath);
            ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
            setZipFileName(path);

            Log.i(TAG, "Output to Zip : " + outputPath);

            for(String file : this.fileList){

                System.out.println("File Added : " + file);
                ZipEntry ze= new ZipEntry(file);
                zos.putNextEntry(ze);

                FileInputStream in =
                        new FileInputStream(path + "/" + file);

                int len;
                while ((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    zos.write(buffer, 0, len);
                }

                in.close();
            }

            zos.closeEntry();
            zos.close();

            Log.i(TAG, "Zip of " + getZipFileName() +" Completed");
        }catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Show the preparations before and show how you call generateFileList().

Comment: Having your device be "rooted" does not in any way change what the main process of the application can do, but only what helper executables can.

Comment: @greenapps See my edit for how generateFileList() is called. The path variable is set when my Directory class is initialized and is the String "/data/data/" concatenated with the package name from PackageManager.getInstallerPackage. By "preparations before" do you mean how the app requests root access?

Comment: Thank you Unem. I saw enough now. But Chris 'the main process of the application' wich one is that? And 'helper executables' where does my app have them?

Comment: @ChrisStratton I'm aware of this, but does the fact I've granted Super User access for the app not mean I should be able to read file contents? Can you suggest a way for me to do this?

Comment: Please see the many other questions here about using 'su' root hacks, as you don't seem to yet understand that "superuser access" does not empower the java code of your app.